# Execute stored procedure from a controller

Tags: c#

I have my class where is the context of the database

```
using APICentralBL.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace APICentralBL.Data
{

    public  class CentralContext : DbContext
    {

      //  private static CentralContext centralContext = null;
        public CentralContext() : base("Context") 
        {
        
        }

        public DbSet<SDN> SDN {  get; set;}
        public DbSet<CALIF> CALIF { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UVT> UVT { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PUNTOV> PUNTOV { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TRANS> TRANS { get; set; }

        public DbSet<PROC> PROC { get; set; }

        public static  CentralContext Create()
        {
            return new CentralContext();
        }


    }
}
```

From here I create the context and start creating the controllers

```
using APICentralBL.Data;
using APICentralBL.DTOs;
using APICentralBL.Models;
using APICentralBL.Repositories.Implements;
using APICentralBL.Services.Implements;
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;

namespace APICentral.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  Controlador de Uvts.
    /// </summary>


    [RoutePrefix("api/Trans")]
    public class TransController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly TransService TransService = new TransService(new TransRepository(CentralContext.Create()));
        private readonly IMapper mapper;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Controlador de Uvts.
        /// </summary>
        public TransController()
        {
            this.mapper = WebApiApplication.MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// /   
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="transDTO"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(TransDTO transDTO)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            try
            {
                var trans = mapper.Map<TRANS>(transDTO);
                trans = await TransService.Insert(trans);
                return Ok(trans);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {return InternalServerError(ex); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<TransDTO>))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            var sdn = await TransService.GetAll();
            var sdnDTO = sdn.Select(x => mapper.Map<TransDTO>(x));
            return Ok(sdnDTO);
        }


    }
}
```

All of the above works fine

I want to create a Get that queries a stored procedure, not a table

I have this example but it doesn't work for me, how could I make it query a procedure instead of a table?

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            try
            {
                string bod = "PV-PRA";
                var result = await ProService.GetAll("sp_prueba @bod", new SqlParameter("@bod", bod)).ToListAsync();
                return Json(result);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

In other words, based on how the get I showed above worked for me, I want it to work the same but calling a procedure

Comment: See [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) and [User-defined function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping)

Comment: install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 6.0.6'. You are trying to install this package into a project that has '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8' as the target, but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Comment: See page 42 (from PDF page number) : https://waterfund.go.ke/watersource/Downloads/Progress%20Database%20Administration.pdf?force_isolation=true

Comment: WebSpeed ? But what I look there, I don't see that that helps me